# selectedIndex is missing from table's rowSelectionChange oEvent

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I have a table that is configured with:

```
selectionBehavior="Row"
selectionMode="Single"
rowSelectionChange="onRowSelectionChange"
```

And the click action is this:

```
onRowSelectionChange: function(oEvent) {
    var selected = oEvent.getSource().getProperty("selectedIndex")
    if (selected === -1) {
        // something happens
    } else {
        // something else happens
    }
},
```

But for some reason, I am getting -1 as my `selectedIndex` when I select any row. Am I missing something here?

I can provide more information if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [getSelectedIndex()](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.table.Table/methods/getSelectedIndex)

```
onRowSelectionChange: function(oEvent) {
    var selected = oEvent.getSource().getSelectedIndex();
    if (selected === -1) {
        // something happens
    } else {
        // something else happens
    }
},
```

Answer (score 2):

According to SAP documentation  - [rowSelectionChange](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.table.Table/events/rowSelectionChange) event

the `rowSelectionChange` event get a `rowIndex` parameter

replace

```
var selected = oEvent.getSource().getProperty("selectedIndex")
```

by

```
var selected = oEvent.getParameter("rowIndex")
```

and it should give you what you expect :)